# Input no deja eliminar contenido

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, validación, input

tengo un problema, estoy trabajando con react js, tengo varios input a los que les hice validaciones para que muestre un mensaje si ingresó más o menos caracteres de los que deben ser:

```
<label htmlFor='serie'>Número de serie</label>
  <input 
    type='text' 
    name='serie' 
    value={data.serialNumber} 
    onChange={e=> {
      e.preventDefault()
      setErrorValidation(false)
      if((e.target.value.length >= 10) && (e.target.value.length < 18)) {
        setData({...data, serialNumber: e.target.value.toUpperCase()})
        setErrorSerial(false)
      } else setErrorSerial(true)
   }}
/>
```

pero cuando quiero eliminar todo lo del input no me deja, ya no pasa de los 10 caracteres.
Alguien podría ayudarme por favor a entender que es lo que me está fallando?
Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si llamas a `setData` dentro de tu `if`, el valor de `data.serialNumber` solo va a cambiar cuando se cumpla la condición del `if`.
Creo que deberías llamar siempre a `setData` ya que el `if` al parecer solo sirve para condicionar la ejecución de `setErrorSerial`:

```
onChange={e=> {
  e.preventDefault()
  setErrorValidation(false)
  const { value } = e.target
  setData({...data, serialNumber: value.toUpperCase()})
  setErrorSerial(!(value.length >= 10 && value.length < 18))
}}
```